# Scrapy: Spider error processing even though same as tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have this very basic spider which should crawl this Url: 
'https://search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot/'

however I get an error that doesn't really say much. I have checked the inundation and it's fine.

```
import scrapy
import json
from pprint import pprint
class SiemensSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'siemens-spider'
    start_urls = ['https://search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot/']
    def parse(self, response):
        results = json.loads(response.body)
        pprint(results)
```

My full log:

```
(base) tobi@derGeraet:~/Dokumente/Dokumente/Python Scripts/Webscraping/siemens/siemens/spiders$ scrapy crawl siemens-spider -L WARN
2019-04-17 14:21:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tobi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/tobi/Dokumente/Dokumente/Python Scripts/Webscraping/siemens/siemens/spiders/siemens_spider.py", line 9, in parse
    results = json.loads(response.body)
  File "/home/tobi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/tobi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/tobi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What is in your `response.body`? // btw, anyway you will get an error on decoding, since you get html, not json.

Comment: The response is a html, not a json.